# setting state inside react context with axios response

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I have an http get request which returns json. I want to store that response in a state variable. 
This is in context.js:

```
switch(action.type) {
        case 'BUSCAR_LIBRO':
            return {
                ...state,
                respuestaJson: axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + action.payload.split(' ').join('+'))
                .then(response => {})
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
```

The value of respuestaJson that I get is promise{}

Comment: is this a redux `reducer`?

Comment: Well yes... That's because this is what `axios` returns... The problem is doing this in your reducer...

Comment: Is not redux. Its context api. Similar

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin what do you mean "The problem is doing this in your reducer"?

Comment: Show please more code, especially this method, because it is not clear what is the `state`

Comment: Well, as @Sagiv b.g said, your code looks more like a reducer than a context. In any cases, you would usually not do such kind of actions in either a reducer (you'd do it in a saga for example), or with the context api, you'd set a slice of your context to reference a function in your context provider... I'll show an example.

Comment: What react-context got to do with your code? Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You have probably right now is wrapping everything into `setState`.

```js
someMethod = () => {
  this.setState(state => {
    ...YOUR CURRENT CODE
  })
}
```

You need to call api, and after update

```js
someMethod = () => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'BUSCAR_LIBRO':
    axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + action.payload.split(' ').join('+'))
    .then(res => {this.setState(...UPDATE)});
  default:
    return null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since we don't have a lot of code, I can only guess what could be useful to you. But here is how it can be done for asynchronous operations:

```
import React, { PureComponent, createContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const getDefaultContext = () => ({
  books: null,
  fetchBooks: () => {},
})

const Context = createContext(getDefaultContext());

class BookProvider extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

   this.fetchBooks = this.fetchBooks.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      books: null,
      fetchBooks: this.fetchBooks,
    };
  }

  fetchBooks() {
    axios
      .get('http://something')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState(prevState => { ...prevState, books: response.books });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <Context.Provider context={this.state}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And then, in some of your children:

```
<Context.Consumer>
  {context => <Button onClick={context.fetchBooks}>Load books</Button>}
</Context.Consumer>
```

But your code really doesn't look like you are using the context API...

Answer (score 0):

first, You need to assign the context to a variable.

```
yourFunction = () => {
  let self = this;
  switch(action.type) {
        case 'BUSCAR_LIBRO':
            return {
                ...state,
                respuestaJson: axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + action.payload.split(' ').join('+'))
                .then(response => {
                 self.foo = response.data;
                 })
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
```

}